# More suitable method to remove 'li' Elements from List?

Tags: javascript, html

This solution below works for adding and removing list items. I had to implement `Math.random()` in order to set a unique id for each element. I was thinking in the professional world this definitely wouldn't cut it considering the chance of a repeating ID.

Wanted to know what would be a more suitable implementation? Any feedback welcome!

Thanks!

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <p id = 'listTitle'> Your List </p>
      <form onsubmit = "return false">
      <input id = 'inputBar' type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Item"></input>
      <input type = "submit" onclick = "getName()"></input>
      <input type = "button" value = "Remove" </input>
      </form>
      <ol id = 'demo'> 
      </ol>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

JS

```
function getName() {

var input = document.getElementById('inputBar').value
var list = document.getElementById('demo')
var entry = document.createElement('li')
entry.setAttribute("id", Math.floor(Math.random()* (100 - 1) + 1 ))
console.log(entry.id)
entry.setAttribute("onclick", "removeName(this.id)")
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input))
list.appendChild(entry)
}

 function removeName(removeID) {
 var listItem = document.getElementById(removeID)
 listItem.remove()
}
```

Comment: Push all new IDs into an array upon creation, remove the  deleted ones and check if the identifier is in the array before assigning it to new items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for dynamic IDs. When appending the new element, just attach a listener that calls `entry.remove()` when clicked. You can also assign to the `textContent` instead of using the unnecessarily verbose `createTextNode` / `appendChild`.

```js
function getName() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('inputBar').value;
  const li = document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
  li.onclick = () => li.remove();
  li.textContent = inputValue;
}
```

```html
<p id='listTitle'> Your List </p>
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input id='inputBar' type="text" placeholder="Enter Item"></input>
  <input type="submit" onclick="getName()"></input>
  <input type="button" value="Remove" </input>
</form>
<ol id='demo'>
</ol>
```